# Faking/Mocking a Javascript object for Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

Quite a large portion of my work day to day involves working with Dynamics CRM and writing JS to extend the functionality on the forms.

Most clientside interaction in Dynamics involves using an object provided for you when the form loads, which is just [Xrm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334351.aspx). So you might have something like:

```
function OnLoad() {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('name').setValue('Stackoverflow!');
    var x = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('name').getValue();
}
```

I tend to write a wrapper for the Xrm object, mainly because it is a lot easier than remembering some of the chaining and end up with something like:

```
function WrappedXrm(realXrm) {
    var xrm = realXrm;

    this.getValue(name) {
        return xrm.getAttribute(name).getValue();
    }
}

//and then use it as so

var myXrm = new FakeXrm(Xrm);
var myXrmValue = myXrm.getValue('Name');
```

I am trying out [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) and wondering how would I go about unit testing in this scenario?

Obviously the example above is a single line, it might not be worth testing it. But assume there was some business logic there that I wanted to test.

The only way I can see is doing some set up before each test along the lines of

```
var fakeXrm = {};
fakeXrm.Page = {};
fakeXrm.Page.getAttribute = function(name) {
    var tempAttr = {};
    tempAttr.getValue = function() {
        return 'A fake value';
    }
}
```

And then testing on `'A fake value'` being returned, but this doesn't 'feel' right to me at all.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Mocks

So in this case, you want to create an instance of WrappedXrm, and pass it an object that mocks the Xrm from your lib ; you need a mock of Xrm.

A first alternative is to write it like you did (which is perfectly valid, if you know what the interface of Xrm is.)

Some libraries like sinon.js or "spies" in the jasmine framework can help you write code like  ;

- create a 'mock' Xrm, to configure what it should return
- create an instance of WrappedXrm with this mock
- call the getValue method of WrappedXrm
- check that some method was called on the mock

But in the case of javascript, simply created a object that has *just* the right properties might be okay.

Note that your tests would break if the structure of the "real" Xrm object changes ; that might be what bother's you, but that's always the risk with mocks...

#### Using the real implementation

If you don't want to test against a mock (which might make sense in case of a wrapper), then  maybe you can write the mimimal code that would create an *actual* Xrm object in your qunit html page (Maybe hardcoding markup ? I don't know the library, so...)

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if it might be worth writing a basic fakeXrm that exposes properties I can assert against - e.g getValueWasCalled, setValueWasCalled etc. and then set them in the fake method implementations. Worth a try I think - thanks!

Comment: @glosrob if you're going to do this, than I guess using a mock library (sinonjs, mockitojs, whatever) would save you some time.